# Omit bad content in sitemap

Tags: google, sitemap, xml-sitemap

My site basically consists out of user generated content (UGC). A user can submit a tutorial. Other users can vote on tutorials. Ratings can be negative too, SE style more or less.

Now I want to generate a dynamic sitemap which adds every tutorial. But I'm necessary interested in adding tutorials with a negative rating to my sitemap. The question is: Will google be mad about it (omitting tutorials)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please understand that Google will largely ignore sitemaps if a site can be effectively crawled. Google will compare what it can crawl with the sitemap to ensure that it can properly crawl the site.

A sitemap is only necessary if a site is extremely large, the content cannot effectively be linked, or if content resides behind a paywall or login.

If you submit a sitemap without the pages with low or negative scores, Google will continue to crawl these pages and not complain at all. However, this does not solve your problem. (I assume.)

If you do no want these pages crawled, you should mark the pages *noindex*. Otherwise, I would not bother with a sitemap at all. SEOs like to suggest creating a sitemap, however, a sitemap has nothing to do with SEO. Many SEOs parrot junk advice and do not understand search technology enough to give proper advice.

Comment: Does make sense. But in my case it could be that Google will have a problem crawling effectively: my index of tutorials is generated by JavaScript (pagination which uses XHR requests to get a small amount of  tutorials).

Comment: @Brettetete I understand. I cannot possible link all of my pages so you and I have valid reasons to have a sitemap. If Google cannot follow the JS links and the pages do not appear within the sitemap, there is no harm nor foul. However, if you can possibly do it, it may be wise to noindex the pages if you do not want them appearing in search just in case.

Comment: the question is: Will google be me about about me hiding content? :|

Comment: @Brettetete No. There is no penalty associated with the sitemap at all. It is mostly a way to communicate with Google - nothing more really.